# Get JSON data from external url and print it HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print a json format data in HTML page.
No matter what I do, I can't print the data in the html page. Here is my code:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://indian-courier-api-premium.vercel.app/api/delhivery/2535101029260?format=jsonp&lang=en&?callback=?", function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The API you're using doesn't support JSONP nor does it support CORS. You'll have to use a proxy

Comment: what type of json format your getting from url?

Comment: Please first confirm are you getting the api data or not?

Comment: @Phil Hi, How can I use proxy? I am very new at this, Could you please tell me?

Comment: @ash This is the data what I'm getting from the URL 
{"status":"success","data":[{"location":"Delhi_Airport_GW (Delhi)","detail":"Bagged at PC","date":"2020-10-13T15:04:59.306000"},{"location":"Delhi_Airport_GW (Delhi)","detail":"Bag Incoming Against Trip","date":"2020-10-13T09:35:24.181000"},....

Comment: @WaqarAkram Yes, if you copy and paste the URL, you can see the JSON data. The data is from an API of a third party

Comment: There are two links at the top of this post with plenty of information for you to read

Comment: Thanks a lot @Phil . The proxy really did the trick. Just used https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ before the JSON URL and it worked